# domain driven design isDirty, isNew

Tags: domain-driven-design

If I'm strictly following DDD, aren't the concepts of IsDirty and IsNew as properties on an entity breaking the rule that the entity is supposed to deal only with it's own logic.  IsDirty/IsNew are things used for persistence.  Even still, I've seen people put this directly in an entity or entity base class.  Isn't this a no no?  What are some other approaches to getting the same functionality and moving it outside of the entity.  Something like an object state tracker?  I'm trying to accomplish this so I can do something like order.AddLine() and then call orderRepository.Save(order).  I'd like to do this without adding logic in every single setter to say it's dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that implementing isNew and isDirty is not a practice acceptable in strict adherence to DDD. Typically you want to use [Unit of Work pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) to handle keeping track of the domain layer changes that need to be communicated to the persistence store.

Comment: Thanks.  Any examples of this NOT using an ORM?